Is it possible to invoke the descriptor deleter from a class?
I have a data-descriptor whose purpose is to read and write data from file, and delete this file :
import os

class ValueFromFile:

    ...

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name
        self.path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.name + '.pickle')

    def __delete__(self, owner):
        print('deleting')
        os.remove(self.path)


It is used by some class attribute:
class C:
    value = ValueFromFile()

Now, i'm trying to invoke the deleter:
From an instance:
>>> del C().value
deleting

Here it does invoke the descriptor __delete__ methode.
From the class:
>>> del C.value


Here it does not invoke the descriptor __delete__ methode.
Why ? Is it possible to make del C.value invoke the __delete__ methode from the descriptor ?

What if you had multiple instances of C? Which file would you expect C.value to delete (or would you expect files for every instance of C to be deleted)?

The final goal is to import C and use C.value without instantiating C. Those values are read from files and C has methods to fill them up if needed. C has also default values if file does not exist.

C.value is a property object. How exactly do you plan on using it? If you want a class-level property, those don't really exist, short of defining a property on an appropriate metaclass that gets used to define C. That said, context managers or the atexit module would be a much better way to manage the lifetime of the file than relying on del statements.

Exactly, I would need class-level property. And I tried a metaclass thing but felt that it is was a bit overkill for my need. Thank you for the hints !

In fact, i think i wont need to use del. I was just testing the behavior of C.value, tests wich bring me here.

when you're trying to delete with del C.value you're actually removing the field value from the class C
class ValueFromFile:
    def __delete__(self, owner):
        print('deleting')

class C:
    value = ValueFromFile()

print(dir(C))
#>>> [..., value]

instance = C() #same as using del C().value later
print(dir(instance))
#>>> [..., value]

del instance.value
print(dir(instance))
#>>> [..., value]
#the key still exists

del C.value
#>>> [...] #value is gone in the class
print(C.value)
#>>> attribute error
# you're deleting the value from the class here
# meaning the value doesn't matter, it's like deleting a key from a dictionary but the dictionary is a class

Sorry for the bad explaination but i can't come up with anything better right now. Also, i don't know which method actually gets called here, possibly __del__ of whatever you are deleting
class Object(dict):
     def __del__(self):
          print("here")
class C:
    value = Object()
del C.value
#>>> here

after a little further testing, it looks like __delete__ is used to delete something "this object from instance" while __del__ is used when del is called "on this object"

"__del__ is used when del is called "on this object"": That is incorrect. See this answer.
